# web2py error: You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, sql, web2py

I have web2py application for which I have to write an SQL query. There is a table called *homework* in which the column of my interest is *receiver*. This column contains a list of students who have received the assignment.
This column is created by

```
db.define_table('homework',
Field('title'),
Field('description'),
Field('sender', db.auth_user),
Field('campus_class', db.campus_class),
Field('send_time', type='datetime'),
Field('completion_time_hw', type='integer'),
Field('attached_files', type='list:string'),
Field('created', type='datetime', default=request.now, writable=False, readable=False),
Field('modified', type='datetime', default=request.now, writable=False, readable=False),
Field('send_notification_on', type='datetime',  writable=False, readable=False),
Field('send_status', type='boolean', default=False),
Field('receiver', type='list:reference auth_user'),
)
```

I need to compare these list values to a column *student* in another table called *student_guardian_relation*.

```
db.define_table('student_guardian_relation',
Field('student',db.auth_user, requires=IS_NULL_OR(IS_IN_DB(db(db.auth_user.user_role == UserRoles.Student),db.auth_user.id,'%(first_name)s %(last_name)s'))),
Field('guardian',db.auth_user, requires=IS_NULL_OR(IS_IN_DB(db(db.auth_user.user_role == UserRoles.Guardian),db.auth_user.id,'%(first_name)s %(last_name)s')))
)
```

But when I try to compare these two values I get an error thats reads:

> < class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'> operator does not exist: text = integer LINE 1: ...rdian_relation, homework WHERE (homework.receiver = student_... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

This is what my code does:

```
print db(db.homework.receiver == db.student_guardian_relation.student).select(db.homework.receiver)
```

Additional info:

When I write:

```
print db().select(db.homework.receiver)
```

I get a list of the receivers as shown in the image.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Something in the DB is an int and something is a string, and postgres is telling you it can't compare those two...it's hard to tell which is which without being able to see a bit more of the code--could you post the actual model classes?

Comment: The receiver is a list and I want to compare it with the student id which is in int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `db.homework.receiver` is a `list:reference` type field, so it stores lists of record IDs, not individual IDs. As such, you must use the `.contains` operator rather than `==` to check whether a particular ID is included in the list.

Internally, `list:reference` fields are stored as text fields with the "|" character delimiting the IDs (e.g., "|1|5|12|32|"). The web2py DAL automatically handles converting between this format and Python lists. Anyway, this is the reason that your use of the `==` operator triggered an error regarding a type mismatch (i.e., your query was comparing a string to an integer).

For further details, check out the relevant [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#list--type--and-contains).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand why I was getting the error and why using .contains fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue related to comparing rows with int. I used

```
db((db.homework.receiver.contains(db.student_guardian_relation.student))
```

I think this compares values in both tables regardless of the types (at least in my case it sort of does this) and you can extend your query further by building on this one.